# htaccess redirect to website root keeping hashtag

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, root, hashtag

Been trying to get the following done

redirect from

http://www.mydomain.com/submissions/#22.322.1

to

http://www.mydomain.com/#22.322.1

So far totaly unsuccesfull, (besides crashing the server).

Help appreciated,
Peter

Comment: FWIW, the fragment (the '#22.322.1' part in this example) isn't actually sent by the browser as part of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Save this into your .htaccess file in  /submission/ subfolder...